# Highlighting rows from results

Tags: php, sql

I have a script which returns 5 columns from  a php result. I am trying to match one of the columns due date against the current date. If the date returned is older I want to highlight that row. It does not seem to for some reason. I have tested my if statement and it work.

```
<?php
    // First of all initialise the user and check for permissions
    require_once "/var/www/users/user.php";
    $user = new CHUser(7);

    // Initialise the template
    require_once "/var/www/template/template.php";
    $template = new CHTemplate();

    // And create a cid object
    require_once "/var/www/WIPProgress/DisplayWIPOnLocation.php";
    $WIPProgress= new CHWIPProgress();
    $content = "<h1>Check WIP Status on Location </h1>";
    $content = 
        "<form action='index.php' method='get' name ='location'>
            <select id='location' name ='location'  >
        <option>Skin Room</option>
                <option>Clicking</option>
                <option>Kettering</option>
        <option>Closing</option>
                <option>Rushden</option>
                <option>Assembly</option>
                <option>Lasting</option>
                <option>Making</option>
                <option>Finishing</option>
                <option>Shoe Room</option> 
             </select>
             <input type='submit' />
         </form>"; 

    if(isset($_GET['location'])) {
         $wip = $WIPProgress->ListWIPOnLocation($_GET['location']);
         $location = $_GET['location'];
         $todays_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

         // Now show the details
         $content .= 
             "<h2>Details for $location </h2>
             <table>
                 <tr>
                     <th>PPDescription</th>
                     <th>Works Order</th>                 
                     <th>Bundle Number</th>
                     <th>Bundle Reference</th>
                     <th>Due Date</th>  
                 </tr>";

         foreach($wip as $x) {
             if(strtotime($x['DueDate']) > strtotime($todays_date)){ 
                 $content .= 
                     "<tr bgcolor='#FF0000'>
                         <td>" . $x['Description'] . "</td>
                         <td>" . $x['WorksOrder'] . "</td>
                         <td>" . $x['Number'] . "</td>
                         <td>" . $x['Reference'] . "</td>
                         <td>" . $x['DueDate'] . "</td>
                     </tr>";
             }
         }
    }
    else {
         $content .= "<h3>Please choose a location to view WIP</h3>";
    }

    $template->SetTag("content", $content);
    echo $template->Display();
?>
```

Is there any classes available in php which highlights rows returned?

Comment: you are missing the normal flow, so you are only printing highlighted cells?

Comment: no i just wanted to force it on

Comment: There is no else to your if statement... I find this strange if you want to display each row.

Comment: What browser are you using? Can you show the generated HTML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining `bgcolor` with `tr` define with each `td` in it.

OR better way to  associate a CSS class to the `tr` and target all the `td` of this `tr` through CSS.

```
$content .= "<tr class='highlight'>...";

<style>
.highlight td
{
  background-color:#FF0000;
}
</style>
```

Comment: thank you that worked But i took advise and added else statement, as it would have not worked otherwise.